# how to add random numbers generated from a for loop

Tags: c++, for-loop, random, sum, numbers

I have to write a program where it generates random numbers (from 1 to 6) and adds (sums) the randomly generated sumbers. So far I've managed to generate 10 random numbers (two pairs: ten numbers for x and another ten for y) My initial goal is to compare the two, which I can with an 'if' statement but so far I cannot figure out how to add the randomly generated numbers together. I tried diferent methods but nothing has worked so far. I am new to c++ so please excuse me for the question ,if it is simple, in advance.
 The code looks like this:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <string>
 using namespace std;

 int main(){
  int sum1=0, sum2=0, x, y;

  for(x = 1; x <= 10; x++) {

    cout << 1 + (rand() % 6) << endl;

     sum1=sum1+x;
  }

   cout<<"----------------"<<endl;

for ( y=1; y<=10; y++){


    cout<<1 + (rand() % 6)<<endl;

    sum2=sum2+y;

}

cout<<"-----------------"<<endl;

 cout<<sum1;


cout<<sum2;

return 0;  
}
```

Comment: You never save the result of `1 + (rand() % 6)` anywhere. Perhaps another variable or two might be useful?

Comment: I tried with another two variables (value1 and value2) and replace them in the formula of ''sum1+=value1'', and before that I added ''cin>>value1''  but it still did not work (outputs 5555, when it should be for example 31)

Comment: Did you remember to assign to `value1` and `value2`? And did you remember to *seed* the random number generator?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are summing your loop counter.  What you need to do is save your randomly generated number into a variable, and then sum that value.

Using your code example, I'd tweak it like this:

```
#include <cstddef>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <iostream>

using std::cout;
using std::endl;
using std::rand;

int main() {
  int sum1=0;
  int sum2=0;

  for(int x = 1; x <= 10; ++x) {
    int n = 1 + (rand() % 6);
    cout << n << endl;
    sum1 += n;
  }

  cout << "----------------" << endl;

  for (int y = 1; y<=10; ++y) {
    int n = 1 + (rand() % 6);
    cout << n << endl;
    sum2 += n;
  }

  cout << "-----------------" << endl;
  cout << sum1 << endl;
  cout << sum2 << endl;

  return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

Comment: it didn't work until I realised you added the <cstddef> library, which I did not know about, I thought that the <cstdlib> was good enough, anyway, with the def library it works, thanks so much, it took me days to figure it out!

Comment: The cstddef header is because I prefer to do `return EXIT_SUCCESS;` instead of `return 0;` at the end of main.  The `EXIT_SUCCESS` token is in cstddef.  The `std::rand` declaration is in cstdlib.

Answer (score 0):

You get 55 for sum1 and sum2 I guess.

If you want to sum up the Random numbers you have to save them.

Hence, something like

```
s1 = 1 + (rand() % 6);
cout << s1 << endl;
sum1 = sum1 + s1
```

Should do the trick.

Comment: it worked only with the library <cstddef>, which was pointed out with one of the answers above, good to know, thank you too!

Comment: Hi, make sure to understand that your summation problem has no relation to the library cstddef. It is really only that you missed saving your results in some variable.

Comment: I did, thank you for pointing it out, took me a while to realise that it was for the return syntax, haha, I tried it your way and it worked just as well, not sure why initially it did not refresh (did not show the output when the syntax was on point) Best wishes!

Answer (score 0):

You need to "seed" the generator. Check out this short video, it will clear things up.

https://www.thenewboston.com/videos.php?cat=16&video=17503

Comment: #include<iostream>
#include<cstdlib>
#include<string>
#include<ctime>
using namespace std;

 int main(){
  int sum1=0, sum2=0, x, y;
    srand(time(0));
  for(x = 1; x <= 10; x++) {
     sum1=sum1+(1 + (rand() % 6));
  }

   cout<<"----------------"<<endl;

  for(x = 1; x <= 10; x++) {
     sum2=sum2+(1 + (rand() % 6));
  }

  cout<<"-----------------"<<endl;
cout<<sum1<<endl;
cout<<sum2;

return 0;
}